# Having trouble with web security

Tags: php, security, web, authentication

The login web page of my website is not secure, whenever typing a username or password on the login page in firefox I get a dialog box saying:

> The connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised.

Should I try prepared statements, or is there another issue? Sorry this is a broad question, but I'm not all too familiar with web security.

Here's my login page code:

```
<?php 
include("connect.php"); 
include('PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps');
   if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if (!connect::query('SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
                if (strlen($username) >= 3 && strlen($username) <= 32) {
                        if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/', $username)) {
                                if (strlen($password) >= 6 && strlen($password) <= 60) {
                                if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                if (!connect::query('SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$email))) {

                                        connect::query('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (null, :username, :password, :email, \'0\')', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':email'=>$email));
                                        gmail_xoauth::sendMail('Welcome to the Website!', 'Your account has been created!', $email);
                                        echo "<h3 class = 'errmessage'>Success!</h3>";


                                } else {
                                        echo '<h3 class = "errmessage">Email already in use!</h3>';
                                }
                        } else {
                                        echo '<h3 class = "errmessage">Invalid email!</h3>';
                                }
                        } else {
                                echo '<h3 class = "errmessage">Invalid password, at least 6 characters!</h3>';
                        }
                        } else {
                                echo '<h3 class = "errmessage">Invalid username, at least 3 characters</h3>';
                        }
                } else {
                        echo '<h3 class = "errmessage">Invalid username</h3>';
                }
        } else {
                echo '<h3 class = "errmessage">User already exists!</h3>';
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if (connect::query('SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
                if (password_verify($password, connect::query('SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['password'])) {
                        $cstrong = True;
                        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
                        $user_id = connect::query('SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
                        connect::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));
                        setcookie("SNID", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
                        setcookie("SNID_", '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
        setcookie("username", $username, time()+3600);
        header("Location: home.php");

                } else {
                        echo '<h3 class = "errmessage">Incorrect Password!Try again</h3><br><br><br>';
                }
        } else {
                echo '<h3 class = "errmessage">User not registered!Try again</h3><br><br><br>';
        }


    }

?>
```

Here's the connect.php file:

```
<?php
class connect
{
    private static function db()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;charset = utf8','username','password');

        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return $pdo;
}

    public static function query($query,$params = array())
    {

        $statement = self :: db()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        if(explode(' ',$query)[0] == 'SELECT')
        {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: its referring to not using https (ssl). its nothing to do with your code

Comment: okay i will look into that

Comment: Besides the answers given, there are other factors to take into account such as file/script/image inclusions which will also cause a problem if they are hard-coded `http://` references. Even though it's not directly answering the question, it does have relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to you having a password field on a non [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) page meaning your page is served over `http` not `https`. You can learn more about the Firefox side of that [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/insecure-password-warning-firefox) and [Mozilla's note to developers here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Insecure_passwords). This can be fixed by adding an SSL certificate to your server.

Some certificates cost money but you can look into [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for free certificates. The main difference between the paid certs and Let's Encrypt certs are the length of validity. At the time of writing they are only good for 3 months however there are tools to automate the renewal.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox added this warning for form elements on pages that are not served using HTTPS that it determines are for sensitive information. This went live in Firefox 52. See [this Mozilla blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/01/20/communicating-the-dangers-of-non-secure-http/) and [this Mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/insecure-password-warning-firefox) for more information.